# Crash on checking ERRSV when embedding Perl in C++ (Win32)

Tags: perl, visual-c++

I am embedding the Perl interpreter (v 5.16.3) in my Visual C++ based code (on Windows 7). The intention is to invoke a user-written subroutine in Perl from my C++ program.

The overall structure of the C++ code to invoke Perl can be thought of as follows:

```
perl_alloc()
perl_construct()
perl_parse()

dSP 

int result = call_argv(funcName, G_ARRAY|G_EVAL|G_KEEPERR, params);

if (SvTRUE (ERRSV)) // <-- crashes here
{
  :
}
```

This code crashes at runtime on the marked line. The problem stems from accessing ERRSV, which would be a macro. Doing some troubleshooting, I found out that the troublemaker is the following attribute:

```
vTHX->Ierrgv
```

i.e., `Ierrgv` is NULL in my case.

If I comment out this error checking (i.e., `SvTRUE`), the code itself works fine, and I know that my Perl script gets executed as well. I can even retrieve the return parameters from the called subroutine!

Can someone tell me **why `Ierrgv` would be NULL, and what exactly that means?**

EDIT:

Making a small change apparently fixes the problem but without detailed insight into `Ierrgv` usage, I am not cofident to consider it as a solution:

```
int result = call_argv(funcName, G_ARRAY|G_EVAL|G_KEEPERR, params);

if ( (result==0) && (SvTRUE (ERRSV) ) // <-- doesn't crash here
{
  :
}
```

The added check on `result` ensures that we evaluate `ERRSV` only when `result` is zero. As I said earlier, apparently this fixes the problem.

Comment: I have a similar issue that fails in v5.14.2, but works in v5.12.4 and v5.17.6. I'm very interested if there's an explanation and a solution.

Comment: It would help to have a minimal runnable demonstration of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`G_KEEPERR` specifically prevents `ERRSV` (`$@`) from being set. Get rid of it.

(Keeps the error message displayed rather than returning it in `$@`.)

> When G_KEEPERR is used, any error in the called code will terminate the call as usual, and the error will not propagate beyond the call (as usual for G_EVAL), but it will not go into `$@`. Instead the error will be converted into a warning, prefixed with the string "\t(in cleanup)". This can be disabled using `no warnings 'misc'`. If there is no error, `$@` will not be cleared.

Comment: seems right...but I feel the Perl documentation needs to be improved in this regard. The construction of this sentence seems strange: <snip>and the error will not propagate beyond the call (as usual for G_EVAL), but it will not go into $@.

Comment: Improved how? It states extremely clearly exactly how exception handling differs from the norm.

Comment: IMHO, use of "but" with a negated statement should be avoided

Comment: So how would you rewrite it? Right now, it follows the "it does A but not B" form, and I don't see a way of rewriting it to your expectations.

Comment: It's becoming a troll now :) The sentence has this form "it does A, and not B, but not C".

Comment: @Jaywalker, Indeed. Your lack of cooperation has been unappreciated. If you change your mind, submit the suggested text using the `perlbug` tool or by emailing `perlbug@perl.org`. Patches preferred.